Unzip version check fails if we add exit 1
unzip --version || exit 1  
Is logging out the VM
Expecting the version check will succeeded with out logging out the ubuntu vm
Ubuntu version: 22.04LTS
Using bash script to install unzip and check the version
it works when i use (unzip --version || exit 1)

I believe it's unzip -v. If you run unzip --version by itself it should complain about the options.

Also is there a reason you want to put || exit 1? It sounds like you're doing this interactively so I'm not sure why you'd want to kick yourself out of the VM just because the version check returned a non-zero status.

unzip --version fails (exits with 10) which is why exit 1 is executed.
From the documentation:
DIAGNOSTICS

10     invalid options were specified on the command line.

The option you want is -v:
OPTIONS

-v     list archive files (verbose format) or show diagnostic version info.


it works when i use (unzip --version || exit 1)

No it doesn't. It still doesn't know what --version means and will exit with 10. The only reason why it doesn't log you out of the VM is because you are doing it in a subshell, so it only exits the subshell with 1. That makes having || exit 1 pointless and you could just as well have made that unzip --version. It will also not log you out of the VM in case unzip isn't found.

or we can use (unzip --version || exit 1)

@AkshayKrison No, it doesn't work.  I updated the answer to explain why
